# Como exibir todo código JS requisitado por um iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

Eu quero exibir um `iframe` com uma página externa e depois mostrar em uma `textarea` todo código JS requisitado pelo `iframe` em questão.

Eu tenho dois problemas: o primeiro é como saber todas as requisições que o `iframe` fez, e depois pegar cada uma e mostrar o código.

Tentei fazer `getScript` e Ajax em URL de JavaScript para colocar no `textarea`, mas tenho problema de *cross-domain*, e quando eu consigo fazer o `request`, não vem um campo `textResponse` para que eu consiga pegar o texto e exibir.

Como faço isso? É possível?

Eu só posso usar linguagem de *frontend*, pode ser qualquer biblioteca, jQuery ou até mesmo puro JavaScript.

Comment: Se você trabalhasse com PHP, eu te ensinaria um jeito de pegar todos os JS pelo domdocument ;)

Comment: No navegador você sempre vai bater no problema de cross origin. O único meio que conheço de fazer uma requisição externa sem esse problema é dentro de uma extensão do navegador. Tanto o Chrome como Firefox permitem realizar requisições externas problemas. No caso do Chrome é possível até capturar todas as requests realizadas pela página com a API de extensões.

Comment: Qual código você fez até o momento?

Comment: Eu acabei resolvendo esse problema com um serviço do yahoo chamado YQL

Comment: Gabriele podes colocar uma resposta com a solução que achaste e com um exemplo?

Comment: Eu acabei resolvendo esse problema com um serviço do yahoo chamado YQL

Comment: Eu queria dizer uma resposta aqui em baixo, no campo das respostas com um exemplo. Obrigado!

Comment: Se for o mesmo domínio você pode obter através do document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.window.document se não será como o @GuilhermeNagatomo falou.

Comment: @Grabrielle, explique melhor? Você quer capturar o javascript dentro do iframe ou fora do iframe? Ou vc só quer capturar o código html do iframe no textarea? Porque iframe não possui código javascript, necessariamente.

Answer (score -3):

Bem, você pode usar o `fetch` pra pegar o codigo das paginas requisitadas.

Exemplo:

```js
const link = 'https://google.com/';

fetch(link)
.then( result => result.text() )
.then( HTML => {
    // ai você faz o que quiser com o codigo HTML da pagina
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Sem o dono do servidor/site explicitamente permitir que o mesmo seja "embedado" por outros via `iframe`, não é possível fazer isso via apenas frontend, devido às restrições de segurança , como a política de mesma origem (CORS) (same-origin policy). Essa política estabelece que um script em uma página não pode acessar o conteúdo de outra página se essas páginas não compartilharem o mesmo origin (esquema, nome de host e porta). Isso significa que você não pode fazer uma solicitação de script para uma página externa usando ajax ou qualquer outra técnica, e também não pode acessar o código-fonte da página externa diretamente usando o DOM.

O que você consegue controlar é o iframe acessar ou não as informações da página principal(pai), usando o atributo `sandbox`.

O atributo `sandbox` permite especificar quais recursos do conteúdo de um iframe são permitidos e quais são bloqueados. Você pode habilitar a opção "allow-scripts" para permitir que o conteúdo do iframe execute scripts.

```js
<iframe src="http://exemplo.com" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Lembrando, esse é um controle onde a página principal, a que está "embedando" o `iframe` dando permissões para o `iframe`  consumir.

Agora, para ter acesso às informações do `iframe`, é preciso adicionar atributos como `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, no `Header` da resposta:

[image: exemplo cabeçalho]

ou via tag `meta` no HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
```

Answer (score -3):

Devido a medidas de segurança do navegador, não é possível acessar diretamente o código fonte do iframe de um domínio externo. Isso é conhecido como a política de mesma origem ou Same Origin Policy.
O que você pode tentar é pegar o HTML e procurar nele o JS mas, pode não funcionar ( ou ser bem complicado) em muitos casos onde a página não é estática.